# Autocomplete TextView Android Example

Tags: database, autocomplete, textview

Im looking for a AutocompleteTextView Example in Android Studio but i dont want the queries to go to the SQLite Db of the phone. I want the app to communicate with a server and an external DataBase.U know....like Youtube does.!!
Thank you....